# Блок текста с автообновлением на jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Добрый день, возникла проблема, в админке есть блок, с живым выводом новых сообщений из истории на jquery

ответ оот сервера формируется следующим образом:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {

        $msg .= $icq[$i]['uid'].'>> '. $icq[$i]['msg'].'<br>';

    }

    echo $msg;
```

вставка ответа в блок происходит каждый 3 секунды следующим кодом:

```
function go() {
var  count = document.getElementById("box");    
  if(count != null)
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://site.ru/api/',
    success: function(data) {     
    $("#box").text(data);   
    }
    });
```

setTimeout(go, 3000);
 }

var update = go();

Проблема в следующем, каждое новое сообщение из истории планировалось выводить с новой строки, для этого в конце каждой итерации цикла в ответ вставляется <br>, но сообщения выводятся следующим образом:

> сообщение 1 `<br>`
> сообщение 2 `<br>`
>  сообщение3 `<br>`

подскажите как убрать `<br>` и сделать нормальный перенос строки ?

Comment: `$("#box").html(data);`

Comment: для переноса можно попробовать не <br/> вставлять, а \n .

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/R6Kz7/1/

[DOM Insertion, Inside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)

[appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: не могли бы вы написать как это использовать ?

Comment: `$("#box").append(data);` 

только лучше сделайте элементы типа `<div>`

Comment: Обновил пост

Comment: Спасибо, помог верхний ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поменять

```
$("#box").text(data);
```

на

```
$("#box").html(data);
```